# Fontawesome with simple_form_for on submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form-for

My goal is to add a Fontawesome icon inside a submit button using simple_form_for

[Final goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Rxa.png)

right now the form is like:

```
            <%= simple_form_for @model, html: {class: "d-flex align-items-end"} do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :model, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => model.id } %>
            <%= f.input :x, label: false, :input_html => { :value => model.x_attr } %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "x", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
            <% end %>
```

And form is:

[Current form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlXGD.png)

Is it possible to add a 
`<i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>`
inside that button with simple_form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way i could find is to create the submit button on pure HTML

```
            <%= simple_form_for @model, html: {class: "d-flex align-items-end"} do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :model :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => model.id } %>
            <%= f.input :quantity, label: false, :input_html => { :value => model.x},  wrap_with: { tag: :span} %>

            <label>m</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-card-index-cart" title="Adicionar ao Carrinho">
                <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>
            </button>

            <% end %>
```

And it works as expected :)

Comment: It works; but simple_form is there to make things easy and save you from typing out so much boilerplate. You lose the benefit of the gem if you resort to just hand coding the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block into the button:

```
<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-secondary" do %>
  <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>
<% end %>
```

That allows you to put any HTML in the button.

So the full form would look like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @model, html: {class: "d-flex align-items-end"} do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :model, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => model.id } %>
            <%= f.input :x, label: false, :input_html => { :value => model.x_attr } %>
            <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-secondary" do %>
                          <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>
             <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still needs to do it, you can do by using `button_tag` instead of `f.submit`, like this:

```
<%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "btn shadow-none position-absolute top-0 end-0 mt-1 me-2" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-paper-plane text-primary fs-4"></i>
<% end %>
```